# XPath taking text with hyperlinks (Python)

Tags: python, html, xpath, lxml

I'm new at using XPath (and I'm a relative beginner at Python in general). I'm trying to take the text out of the first paragraph of a Wikipedia page through it.

Take for instance the Python Page (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_(programming_language))

if I get it into a variable

```
page = requests.get("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_(programming_language)")
tree = html.fromstring(page.content)
```

Then I know the desired paragraph is on XPath `/html/body/div[3]/div[3]/div[4]/div/p[1]`

So I take that text into a variable

```
first = tree.xpath("/html/body/div[3]/div[3]/div[4]/div/p[1]/text()")
```

Resulting on this output

```
[' is an ', ' ', ' for ', '. Created by ', ' and first released in 1991, Python has a design philosophy that emphasizes ', ', notably using ', '. It provides constructs that enable clear programming on both small and large scales.', '\n']
```

As you can see I'm missing the words/sentences that are inside of web links.

Answer (score 1):

The links themselves are nodes that you need to descend.

```
/html/body/div[3]/div[3]/div[4]/div/p[1]//text()
```

Answer (score 1):

Your XPath query matches the text child nodes of that node only. The text of the embedded links live on another node and are therefore excluded.

1. To descend use `//text()` as suggested; this will retrieve the text value of any descending node starting from the node in question.

   ```
    /html/body/div[3]/div[3]/div[4]/div/p[1]//text()
   ```
2. Alternatively, you can select the node in question itself and retrieve the text using a parser method `text_content()` to retrieve the text including all child nodes.

```
lxml import html
import requests

page = requests.get('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_(programming_language)')
tree = html.fromstring(page.content)
firstp = tree.xpath('/html/body/div[3]/div[3]/div[4]/div/p[1]')
firstp[0].text_content()
```