# Scrapy: Extracting both text AND hyperlink text using xpath

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

I am trying to scrape all of the paragraph text, including the hyperlink text, within a specific div class. If I use the following -

```
item['body']=response.xpath('//div[@class="example-class"]//p/text()').extract()
```

this results in all of the paragraph text to be extracted, but not the hyperlinks inside it. The results look like:

> To find more information you can ,, and investigate further.

However, if I use //a instead of //p as follows -

```
item['body']=response.xpath('//div[@class="single-content"]//a/text()').extract()
```

this results in all of the hyperlinks being extracted but none of the paragraph text.

I understand why this is happening, but am not sure on how to properly extract both the paragraph text AND the hyperlinked text. Thank you very much.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Two conditions using OR in XPATH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12562597/two-conditions-using-or-in-xpath)

Comment: Issue solved. The links themselves are nodes that I needed to decend by changing //p/text  ->  //p//text.

Ref - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51354279/xpath-taking-text-with-hyperlinks-python